# Get mouse position on window.resize

Tags: jquery, resize, window, position, mouse

..got a "tiny little" problem with mouse position after resizing browser window.
I have a form which is displayed on a click event and positoned by script as follows:

```
$('#whatever').click(function(event){
   $('#dialog').css('left', event.pageX);
   $('#dialog').css('top', event.pageY);
});
```

Works fine so the dialog apears on left top of current mouse position.
If I now resize the windows while the dialog is shown, it looses "orientation" :-)
So I need to refresh to the current mouseposition on

```
$(window).resize(function(event){
   $('#dialog').css('left', event.pageX);
   $('#dialog').css('top', event.pageY);
});
```

But guess what, this does not work. How can I get the position without having a
mousemove or click just after having resized the window - is that possible?

Here is a jsfiddle sample to try out: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/AyLgV/9/)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raising the click event onResize might work. Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $(document).trigger('click'); 
});
```